# Intent putextra not working in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to start an activity when I click on a item of a ListView, I have this code on the first activity:

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                               // Starting single contact activity
                String id_lo = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idProducto)).getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        CaracteristicasProducto.class);
                in.putExtra("id", id_lo);
                startActivity(in);                                       }
        });
```

And I use this code for reading the putExtra in the CaracteristicasProducto.class

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in new Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: with that now works the intent, but i have another error with a asynctask, here is the error and the CaracteristicasProducto.class: Error: tny.cz/008b34ba and the class: tny.cz/5b7b7caf

Comment: That would be a new question :)

Comment: When you post the new question, make sure you post the `AsyncTask` code and the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

what  you trying is right.is you getting any exception or error? is you move to activity CaracteristicasProducto.class sucessfully?